# symfony same form to edit multiple entities

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

i'm updating a website and i'm facing an issue : there are two tables for news : one for public news, one for internal news. the two tables are exactly the same. and i can't change anything on these tables

Here is the entity :

```
class News
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;
}
```

I need to make a form to add news in both tables but as they are exactly the same, is it possible (and how to make this) to make one form with two buttons "post private" and "post public" and persist the object in the correct table ?

Also, in the formType, there is this piece of code to bind a form on an entity sowhat do i need to put here ?

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'S2d\WebsiteBundle\Entity\News'
        ));
    }
```

Comment: You might be able to add a field `$isPrivate` to the News entity and use it for both public & private news.  Set `$news->isPrivate()` in the controller.

Comment: unfortunately, i can't change the database so i can't add a field on it... i'm stuck with the two entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there exists two entities `PrivateNews` and `PublicNews` and a form type `NewsType` without a `data_class` defined in default options.

In a controller, try something like:

```
$privateNews = new PrivateNews();
$form = $this->createForm(new NewsType(), $privateNews);
```

and similarly with `$publicNews`.